# Custom action item background in Android toolbar

Tags: android, background, selector, toolbar

I am building android app with app compact theme, as you know `api 21` was deprecated `actionbar` and replace by `toolbar`. Now i can not custom background of action item on toolbar by drawable selector. Please tell me what is way? This is my code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        style="@style/myToolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<style name="myToolbar">
        <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="navigationContentDescription">@string/abc_action_bar_up_description</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the "android:actionBarItemBackground" like this:

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_item_ripple</item>
```

This is set in my values-v21 styles.xml.

Comment: Where i cant put your code? In toolbar style or app style?

Comment: I set this for my theme.

Comment: Thanks, but it not working. I have been achieved by `<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>
<item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>`

Comment: Did you try without the "android" prefix? In your normal styles.xml? This should apply to toolbar then.

Comment: how to do the same for the "up" button?